# Laravel 5.5, Display news data from two tables

Tags: sql, laravel

I am new to laravel and I experience some trouble. I try to obtain data stored in two different tables and display them:

News.php (model)

```
    public static function Data($category) {
    $perPage = config('var.news.perPage');

    if ($category) {
        $news = News::orderBy('id', 'desc')->where('category', $category)->SimplePaginate($perPage);
    } else {
        $news = News::orderBy('id', 'desc')->SimplePaginate($perPage);
    }

    return $news;
}
```

This is how I grab all data from News table which struct is:

```
id, title, body, created_at updated_at, created_by, updated_by, category
```

The category column contains values separated by comma, e.g. 1,2,3,4

Now, I have another table, News_Cat which has `id, name` columns.

In another method I try to grab the filters names against values stored in category column of News table

```
    public static function getFilterNames($id) {

    $filters = DB::table('News_Cat')
        ->select('News_Cat.name as name')
        ->leftJoin('News', DB::raw('CAST(News_Cat.id as nvarchar)'), DB::raw('ANY(SELECT(News.category))'))
        ->where('News.id', $id)
        ->get();

    return $filters;
}
```

However, it completely does not work. What I try to achieve is to display filter name in view.blade as 'name' value for specified filter from News_Cat

```
            @if($news->count())
        @foreach($news as $article)
        <a href="{{ route('news.show', $article->id) }}" class="item angled-bg" data-filters="{{ $filters }}">
            <div class="row">
```

So as result I would get e.g. `data-filters="news, update, hot, latest">` instead data-filters="1,2,3,4">

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use eloquent!

In your News Model

```
public function getFiltersAttribute(){
       $categories = explode(',', $this->category);
       return implode(', ', NewsCat::find($categories)->pluck('name')->toArray());
}
```

then in your view :

```
{{ $article->filters }}
```

will output `news, update, hot, latest`

**BUT**

You should use a pivot table between your categories and your news, it would be much easier.
This method can't allow you to eager load the relationship and make a request for each news

If you can't change your database structure, I can propose you this:

In the boot method of your AppServiceProvider:

```
Config::set('tags', NewsCat::all());
```

THEN

```
public function getFiltersAttribute(){
       $categories = explode(',' $this->category);
       return implode(', ', config('tags')->whereIn('id', $categories)->pluck('name')->toArray());
}
```

**MANY TO MANY METHOD**

I am using laravel naming convention for the table :

news, categories_news (the pivot), and categories

You will have 2 models : New and Category

In your New Model

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)
}
```

in your Category Model :

```
public function news(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(New::class);
}
```

if you are not using laravel naming conventions, you will have to customize these raltionship like this  : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am going to try your suggestion. theoretically I can change structure BUT then it would require 3 tables what I wanted to avoid, e.g.

- News
- NewsType
- NewsCat

where NewsType would store list of available news types and NewsCat an entry for each type of every news. In such case the NewsCat would grow up endless as would store as many entries for each news as many types is assigned to the news. Or maybe having better suggestion?

Comment: You would have 3 tables : news, categories_news (the pivot) and categories
And yes, the pivot table could grow pretty quickly but don't worry ! That's the design of Database :), you will never request this entire table anyway !

And it will be much more easier to retrieve all the news belonging to one category! 
As a best practice, never store relation information in a non relational way in your database

Comment: I tried your previous suggestion and it works, so I marked it as proper answer (you just miss command inside explode). However, I think I decided to go for 3 tables. Would you be kind to give me a clue how to build connection among the 3 tables in Laravel - code part of course - I was thinking to use BelongsToMany..? This framework still looks magic to me in some aspects. Thank you in advance

Comment: All this looks so simple after all that I feel shame I asked, however great I can understand things already! Except one.. in case 1 when we used implode/explode: {{ $article->filters }}

Where from "filters" came from?!. In your code there is no filters word defined in any scope, how come it is available within "$article->" after doing the explode/implode?

Comment: It came from the getter : getFiltersAttribute(), you can read this for more infos :https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor